# Convert timestamp to integer

Tags: matlab, datetime

How can I convert the following timestamp into the an integer form, ideally milliseconds after 1970....

```
       s = '2014-02-11-00_40_05'
```

I have tried using:

```
       out = datevec(s)
```

However I receive an error saying 'Too many date fields in
2014-02-11-00_40_0'

Thanks

Comment: Is 02 a month or a day-of-the-month?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [`datenum`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datenum.html) with a format specifier:

```
>> datenum(s,'yyyy-mm-dd-hh_MM_ss')

ans =

   7.3564e+05
```

Convert to epoch:

```
mtime = datenum(s,'yyyy-mm-dd-hh_MM_ss');
unix_time = round(8.64e7 * (mtime - datenum('1970', 'yyyy')))
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming `02` in your example is month (otherwise change format string in the obvious way):

```
datenum('2014-02-11-00_40_05','yyyy-mm-dd-HH_MM_SS')
```

gives you seconds after Jan-1-0000. From that it's easy to get miliseconds after 1970:

```
( datenum('2014-02-11-00_40_05','yyyy-mm-dd-HH_MM_SS') - ...
  datenum('1970-01-01-00_00_00','yyyy-mm-dd-HH_MM_SS') ) * 1000
```